# How to pass current file name with a different path to the command line

Tags: filesystem, multiple-files

Is there any way to make the special symbol `%` work with path names on the command line? For instance, I'd like to do:

```
:diffsplit Path\to\other\directory\%
```

So that I can do a `@:` to quickly compare files of the same name. However, this just opens up a new buffer called `%`.

Of course I *could* do:

```
:exe 'diffsplit Path\to\other\directory\'.expand('%')
```

But this is cumbersome as I can't tab complete directories when typing the command.

Is there any other better way to do this?

[Here's a related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/bring-up-the-current-file-name-for-edition-in-the-command-line), but it doesn't address my situation exactly.

Edit: Just to clarify, I would like to be able to re-use the command exactly for different files. So a solution that simply autofills the current file in the command line will not work. The same command needs to work for *different* file names.

Comment: You can use a cmap for % such that it expands to filename, that might help :D

Comment: This has the same problem that Kent's solution has. As soon as you press `%`, it will fill to the filename, but then when I want to reuse that line, the old filename will still be present. I would like the % to dynamically insert the current filename, whatever that happens to be at the time without having to retype it.

Comment: `:diffsplit Path/to/other/directory/%:t`

Comment: Wow, I thought I tried that, but you're right that works! Thanks! If you want to put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that it's a stupid Windows problem. The remedy to this is to simply use forward slashes in the path name. i.e. `:diffsplit Path/to/other/directory/%` works just fine.

I've remedied this on my system by using the option `set shellslash` which defaults to using forward slashes even on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, the backslash is used both to escape the special meaning of `%`, and is the default path separator on Windows. Vim can't tell which you had in mind.

Comment: See, I thought of that. So I figured that I could just do a `directory\\%` but that still didn't work. IDK, but I guess it doesn't matter since forward slashes solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Special characters (see `:h cmdline-special`) and filename modifiers (see `:h filename-modifiers`) are expanded on the command line, so:

```
:diffsplit Path/to/other/directory/%:t
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is ok for you:

```
:diffsplit Path/to/somewhere/<c-r>%
```

Just one more keystroke to your original, the `<C-r>`, in order to fill the `%` register value.

Comment: This still doesn't allow for using `@:` for future files as it "hard codes" the current file name.

Comment: then wrap a custom command like `:Mydiff /path/to/there/` so the path could be tab completed. just pass this to your command/function with `exec`